# jQuery toggle box not working in Firefox- jsfiddle

Tags: jquery

I wrote a simple toggle box using jQuery and it works in Safari but not in Firefox. I don't know why.

It's as simple as:

```
jQuery(function($){

    $(".ipro_toggle_content").hide();
    $("h4.ipro_toggle").click(function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).next(".ipro_toggle_content").slideToggle();
    }); 

});
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kaa400ur/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not defined `event` in the click handler. It should be,

```
 $("h4.ipro_toggle").click(function(event){
```

Comment: I have to wait 10 minutes